# ggplot2 heatmap scaling row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a heatmap. I have a csv file that has a list of samples, and data at numerous timepoints. So it looks like this

```
Sample 1h 2h 3h 4h 5h 6h 7h
Test1 
Test2
```

except much bigger and obviously filled with data. My goal is to make a heatmap, so that I can see visually if there is a higher measurement at earlier timepoints. So I dont really care what the values are of each sample in relation to each other. I care which timepoints had the largest values for each sample.

I can make a heatmap but Im fairly certain when it scales, it is scaling each column. But for what I want to do I believe it should be scaling each row. How do I do this? Thank you

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(scales)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

data <- read.table('HB-1ng-1.5000.matrix', header = T, sep = '\t')
data.m <- melt(data)
data.m <- ddply(data.m, .(variable), transform, rescale =     scale(value))
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, Sample)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")
```

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example it will help get you get a more complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about rescaling before melting:

```
dataRowNorm <- t(apply(data, 1, function(x) x/sum(x)))
```

Then melt, rename columns possibly and pass to ggplot.

Comment: alternatively use `scale()` which does column-wise scaling (hence the transpose beforehand): `dataRowNorm = t(scale(t(data)))`